# jQuery UI - Multiple autocomplete - inconsistent results

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have the following `tags.json` file:

```
     [
        {"label" : "Aragorn"},
        {"label" : "Arwen"},
        {"label" : "Bilbo Baggins"},
        {"label" : "Boromir"}
     ]
```

And the following javascript code (The same [from the working demo](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote)):

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    function split( val ) {
      return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
      return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( "#people" )               //DIFF FROM DEMO
      // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
      .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      })
      .autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
          $.getJSON( 'tags.json', {                           //DIFF FROM DEMO
            term: extractLast( request.term )
          }, response );
        },
        search: function() {
          // custom minLength
          var term = extractLast( this.value );
          if ( term.length < 2 ) {
            return false;
          }
        },
        focus: function() {
          // prevent value inserted on focus
          return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          var terms = split( this.value );
          // remove the current input
          terms.pop();
          // add the selected item
          terms.push( ui.item.value );
          // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
          terms.push( "" );
          this.value = terms.join( ", " );
          return false;
        }
      });
  });
  </script>
```

But when I type for example: "`ar`" in my input box, I get `Aragorn, Arwen, Bilbo Baggins` and `Boromir`. I can't figure out why `Bilbo` and `Boromir` are in the results ? I should only get `Aragorn` and `Arwen` because these strings contain the 'ar' string...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the jQuery example the `$.getJSON()` function calls some server side script that does something with the term parameter, i.e. filters the names. The `tags.json` file, in your case, is returned as is, which includes all results. If you want to filter results based on something, e.g. the term entered, you need to apply that filtering before you call response (which is currently the callback of your `$.getJSON()` function).